# How to change data visible range to % percent

Tags: html, css

I am using this for my header that changes in a one page scroll up and down page. I noticed that it's not responsive so i am asking you if you maybe know a way to make that responsive. Like changing the 0-690 into a percentage so that it will work on mobile and also on a tv screen.

HTML

```
 <div class="header header-1" data-visible-range="0-690">Portfolio</div>
 <div class="header header-2" data-visible-range="691-2100">Services</div>
 <div class="header header-3" data-visible-range="2101-">Contact</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-1 {
    background-color:dimgray;
    display: block;

}

.header-2 {
    background-color:dimgray;
}

.header-3 {
    background-color:dimgray;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:8vmax;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition: visibility .4s, opacity .4s ease-in-out;opacity:0;
    font-size:4vmax;padding:1.58vmax;color:white;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you create a (working) jsfiddle with an example? I mean, if the header has a `width:100%`, it should be responsive and the example you have just given should be working perfectly fine. I believe there would be something else wrong with your code. My first assumption would be that you have a wrapper around your header which is not responsive.

Comment: Is it oke to save our time and just give my website. www.gester.nl If you test it on a phone its not accurate and i am not using media queries now. On my tv screen which is a big one it also doesnt work

Comment: If I were you, I'd fix those mistakes first. Your meta is outside of your `<head>` tags. You should really fix tose issues before you can even think about making it responsive. Also, put this meta tag inside your `<head>`: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: @NoobishPro Oke i did that and updated that. Is there a way to fix the problem?

Comment: The problem is more with the mobile then with the tv screen. The tv screen misses like 10% in height before having the right name displayed. And with a phone it misses the whole thing, the title stay's at porftolio (safari Iphone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What if, instead of basing it off pixels, you just checked to see if an element hit the top of the page, and then changed the header?**

We'll call these elements "triggers." See my code below for an example of how they work.

```js
let updateHeader = () => {
  let scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    triggerTitle = "Hi";
  $('.trigger').each((i, el) => {
    let topPos = $(el).offset().top,
      distance = topPos - scrollTop;
    if (distance < 0)
      triggerTitle = $(el).data('title');
  });
  $('header h2').text(triggerTitle);
}

$(window).scroll(updateHeader);
$(window).on('touchmove', updateHeader);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

p {
  margin: 200px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <header><h2>Hi</h2></header>
  <p class="trigger" data-title="section1">
    trigger1
  </p>
  <p class="trigger" data-title="section2">
    trigger2
  </p>
  <p class="trigger" data-title="section3">
    trigger3
  </p>
</div>
```

As you scroll down the page, each trigger hits the top of the page, and the text in the header will change to the the value of the latest trigger's `data-title`. You could position these triggers appropriately above each of your website's sections, so that, no matter what size the screen, the header should update at the right time. [Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/JavaSpyder/pen/MQXYxb).

**EDIT**

Try this JS instead for maximum compatibility (no [es6](http://es6-features.org/) involved).

```
function updateHeader() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    triggerTitle = "Hi";
  $('.trigger').each(function(i, el) {
    var topPos = $(el).offset().top,
      distance = topPos - scrollTop;
    if (distance < 0)
      triggerTitle = $(el).data('title');
  });
  $('header h2').text(triggerTitle);
}

$(window).scroll(updateHeader);
$(window).on('touchmove', updateHeader);
```

Comment: Works perfect on bigger tv screen, but doesn't work with phone, it responds better but i will see what happens tomorrow if i just change in a in "media query" for javascript. Then i will have to use distance < -'200'. Or just make other triggers which only triggers in that screen size. Thanks for your explanation and for your time!

Comment: @user9356960 You're welcome. But what kind of phone did you test it on? Worked fine on mine.

Comment: I tested on a iphone 7

Comment: @user9356960 Ah, Safari is the problem-child when it comes to mobile scroll events. Tested on Firefox, Chrome, Android, DuckDuckGo, and Samsung Internet for mobile, and they all worked fine.

Comment: I noticed today that that code doesnt work in internet explorer 11, do you have a fix for that maybe?

Comment: @user9356960 Please see the edit at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Thanks for answering on the same day, you made me stress less haha. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hey, no one is asnwering my other question can you maybe take a look at it, i am sure a pro like you knows how to fix that code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954284/want-to-make-change-color-of-menu-in-scroll-layout-page